# "incorrect parameters" when I want to format CTime in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, format

I've got a DataTimePicker in mfc. Now, I want to format the value to a String.
I format the value with

```
CTime m_BDate;

m_DataTimePicker.GetTime (m_BDate);
m_Bithdate= m_BDate.Format ("%d-%m-%Y");
```

But theres a problem. And a pretty strange problem. Whenever the value is < 1970, it doesnt work. So, **01.01.1970** works. **12.31.1969** doesnt. There comes the message "incorrect parameters". I really have no idea why.

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly what the specs are saing (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/78zb0ese%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). The lower range is 1.1.1970.

May be it is better to use COleDateTime or SYSTEMTIME to overcome such limitations. Again read the docs about [GetTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt32ce9h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).